# ASP. NET Gridview with DataSourceID not binding properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a page that uses a gridview which has a datasourceID declared, the files display correctly. However, whenever i update a photo of the gridview, the gridview does not update correctly, despite the photo in my folders where the gridview retrieves from being updated already. The only way i can get them to retrieve the right photos are if i actually press F5 or reload the project.
The gridview is also inside a updatepanel.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>   
        <div class="overlay" align="center">
            <div class="over">
            <img alt="progress" src="images/loader.gif"/>
           Processing...        </div> 
    </div>  
        </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
<div id="staffList">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" EnableCaching="false" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1Entities %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM (SELECT Staff.[StaffID], Staff.[StaffName], Staff.[PhoneNo], Staff.[Photo], Staff.[EmpmType], Staff.[AcadStaff], Designation.[DesignationName], Section.[SectionName], Groups.[GroupName], Staff.[InternetAddr], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Designation.[SortingOrder]) AS Rownum FROM Staff LEFT JOIN Designation ON Designation.[DesignationID] = Staff.[DesignationID] LEFT JOIN Groups ON Groups.[GroupID] = Staff.[GroupID] LEFT JOIN Section ON Section.[SectionID] = Staff.[SectionID] WHERE (Staff.[StaffName] IS NOT NULL)) AS test1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT Staff.[StaffID], Staff.[StaffName], Staff.[PhoneNo], Staff.[Photo], Staff.[EmpmType], Staff.[AcadStaff], Designation.[DesignationName], Section.[SectionName], Groups.[GroupName], Staff.[InternetAddr], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Designation.[SortingOrder]) AS Rownum FROM Staff LEFT JOIN Designation ON Designation.[DesignationID] = Staff.[DesignationID] LEFT JOIN Groups ON Groups.[GroupID] = Staff.[GroupID] LEFT JOIN Section ON Section.[SectionID] = Staff.[SectionID] WHERE (Staff.[StaffName] IS NULL)) AS test2;"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Staff Where StaffID=@DSid" DataSourceMode="DataSet" CacheKeyDependency="MyCacheDependency">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="DSid" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataKeyNames="StaffID" CssClass="table table-striped table-condensed" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="50px" Width="40px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Photo", "~/StaffPhoto/{0}") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffID" HeaderText="Staff ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StaffID"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="Staff Name" SortExpression="StaffName"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNo" HeaderText="Ext. No" SortExpression="PhoneNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DesignationName" HeaderText="Designation Name" SortExpression="DesignationName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InternetAddr" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="InternetAddr" />
                    <%--            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpmType" HeaderText="Employment Type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AcadStaff" HeaderText="Staff Type" />--%>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btndelete" runat="server" OnClick="btndelete_Click" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                                ForeColor="Black" />

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnUp" OnClick="Update_Click" ForeColor="Black">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="white" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="black" />
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="pagination-ys" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="white" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="white" ForeColor="black" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <span style="color: red">* No Data Found.</span>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; height: 50px;">
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind for pageload binding

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    }
```

On Select for row

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string subgpID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        BllStaff bs = new BllStaff();
        string sName = bs.GetStaffName(subgpID);
        if (sName == "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "StaffErrorMessage();", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("StaffListDetails.aspx?staffid=" + subgpID);
        }
    }
```

StaffUpdate Page CS

```
public partial class StaffUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UT"] as string))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");
        }
        lbMessage.Text = "";

        string ID = Request.QueryString["staffid"].ToString();

        lblSID.Text = ID;
        tbStaffID.Text = ID;
        if (Session["UT"].ToString() == "Admin")
        {
            ddlAT.Items.Remove("Admin");
        }
        if (ID == Session["StaffID"].ToString())
        {
            if (Session["UT"].ToString() == "Power Admin")
            {
                //Button1.Visible = true;
                OPassword.Attributes.Remove("style");
                NPassword.Attributes.Remove("style");
                NCPassword.Attributes.Remove("style");
            }
        }
        tbStaffID.ReadOnly = true;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UT"].ToString() != "Power Admin")
            {
                if (Session["UT"].ToString() != "Admin")
                {
                    ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Staff", "Staff"));
                    ddlAT.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ID == Session["StaffID"].ToString()) { ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "Admin")); }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Staff", "Staff"));
                        ddlAT.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ID == Session["StaffID"].ToString())
                {
                    ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Power Admin", "Power Admin"));
                    ddlAT.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    BllAccount utAc = new BllAccount();
                    string utAccount = utAc.GetStaffUT(ID);
                    if (utAccount == "Admin")
                    {
                        ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "Admin"));
                        ddlAT.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Staff", "Staff"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ddlAT.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Staff", "Staff"));
                        ddlAT.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Admin", "Admin"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }




    }
    private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SID = tbStaffID.Text;
        string oldP = Encrypt(tbPasswordOld.Text);
        string newP = tbPasswordNewC.Text;
        string ut = ddlAT.SelectedValue;
        string fileName = "";
        string OID = Request.QueryString["Staffid"].ToString();
        if (tbStaffID.Text != "")
        {
            if (this.ImageFileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                if (tbPasswordNewC.Text != "" || tbPasswordOld.Text != "")
                { //update id, password, photo and UT
                    //if (RegularExpressionValidator2.IsValid)
                    if (tbPasswordNewC.Text != "" && tbPasswordOld.Text != "")
                    {
                        string strsql = "select * FROM Account WHERE UserID='" + SID + "' and Password='" + oldP + "'";
                        DataTable dt = sql.ExecTable(strsql);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string[] validFileTypes = { "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg" };
                                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ImageFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();
                                bool isValidFile = false;
                                for (int i = 0; i < validFileTypes.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    if (ext == "." + validFileTypes[i])
                                    {
                                        isValidFile = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!isValidFile)
                                {
                                    lbMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                                    lbMessage.Text = "* Invalid File. Please upload a File with extension " +
                                                   string.Join(", ", validFileTypes);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ImageFileUpload.FileName);
                                    string extion = fi.Extension;
                                    Session["fileEx"] = extion;
                                    fileName = "Ori" + SID + extion;
                                    //create instance for image class
                                    System.Drawing.Image myimg = default(System.Drawing.Image);
                                    //get uploaded image input stream
                                    using (myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
                                    {
                                        //resize it using thumbnailimage method
                                        int width = myimg.Width;
                                        int height = myimg.Height;
                                        double bthumbWidth = 300 * width / height;
                                        int thumbWidth = Convert.ToInt32(bthumbWidth);
                                        myimg = myimg.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, 300, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                                        MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
                                        //Save it in the server images folder
                                        myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\StaffPhoto\\Ori\\" + fileName), myimg.RawFormat);
                                        myimg.Dispose();
                                        //string strFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/StaffPhoto/") + "\\" + fileName;
                                        //this.ImageFileUpload.SaveAs(strFilePath);
                                        imgUpload.ImageUrl = "~/StaffPhoto/Ori/" + fileName;
                                    }
                                    panCrop.Visible = true;
                                    string up = "a";
                                    Session["UpdateP"] = up;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                lbMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                                lbMessage.Text = ex.Message + "* The Photo has failed to update. Please try again later!";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lbMessage.Text = "* Password Wrong!";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbMessage.Text = "* Both password field must fill in!";
                    }
                }
                else //update photo, id and UT
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] validFileTypes = { "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "ico", "jpe" };
                        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ImageFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();
                        bool isValidFile = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < validFileTypes.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (ext == "." + validFileTypes[i])
                            {
                                isValidFile = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isValidFile)
                        {
                            lbMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            lbMessage.Text = "* Invalid File. Please upload a File with extension " +
                                           string.Join(", ", validFileTypes);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ImageFileUpload.FileName);
                            string extion = fi.Extension;
                            Session["fileEx"] = extion;
                            fileName = "Ori" + SID + extion;
                            //create instance for image class
                            System.Drawing.Image myimg = default(System.Drawing.Image);
                            //get uploaded image input stream
                            using (myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
                            {
                                //resize it using thumbnailimage method
                                int width = myimg.Width;
                                int height = myimg.Height;
                                double bthumbWidth = 300 * width / height;
                                int thumbWidth = Convert.ToInt32(bthumbWidth);
                                myimg = myimg.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, 300, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                                MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
                                //Save it in the server images folder
                                myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\StaffPhoto\\Ori\\" + fileName), myimg.RawFormat);
                                myimg.Dispose();
                                //string strFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/StaffPhoto/") + "\\" + fileName;
                                //this.ImageFileUpload.SaveAs(strFilePath);
                                imgUpload.ImageUrl = "~/StaffPhoto/Ori/" + fileName;
                            }
                            panCrop.Visible = true;
                            string up = "b";
                            Session["UpdateP"] = up;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lbMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lbMessage.Text = ex.Message + "* The Photo has failed to update. Please try again later!";
                    }
                }
            }
            else //update password, id and UT
            {
                if (tbPasswordNewC.Text != "" || tbPasswordOld.Text != "")
                { //update id, password, photo and UT
                    //if (RegularExpressionValidator2.IsValid)
                    if (tbPasswordNewC.Text != "" && tbPasswordOld.Text != "")
                    {
                        string strsql = "select * FROM Account WHERE UserID='" + SID + "' and Password='" + oldP + "'";
                        DataTable dt = sql.ExecTable(strsql);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string upMessage = "You are trying to update the information for staff: " + SID;
                            string no = "3";
                            Response.Redirect("AlertUpdate.aspx?MessageNO=" + no + "&UpdateMessage=" + upMessage + "&UpdateStaffid=" + SID + "&fileN=" + fileName + "&NewPass=" + newP + "&UserT=" + ut);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lbMessage.Text = "* Password Wrong!";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbMessage.Text = "* Both password field must fill in!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string upMessage = "You are trying to update the information for staff: " + SID;
                    string no = "4";
                    Response.Redirect("AlertUpdate.aspx?MessageNO=" + no + "&UpdateMessage=" + upMessage + "&UpdateStaffid=" + SID + "&fileN=" + fileName + "&NewPass=" + newP + "&UserT=" + ut);

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lbMessage.Text = "* Staff ID must be provided";
        }
    }

    private void CheckName()
    {
        string SID = tbStaffID.Text;
        BllStaff bs = new BllStaff();
        string sName = bs.GetStaffName(SID);
        if (sName == "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("StaffListAdSearch.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("StaffListDetails.aspx?staffid=" + SID);
        }
    }
    protected void btnUpNewP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uploadNewP.Visible = true;
        uploadNewPD.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string staffid = tbStaffID.Text;
        string role = ddlAT.SelectedValue;
        Response.Redirect("AlertUSuc.aspx?staffid=" + staffid + "&role=" + role);
    }

    protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SID = tbStaffID.Text;
        string oldP = Encrypt(tbPasswordOld.Text);
        string newP = tbPasswordNewC.Text;
        string ut = ddlAT.SelectedValue;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(imgUpload.ImageUrl);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/StaffPhoto/Ori"), fileName);
        string cropFileName = "";
        string cropFilePath = "";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.Drawing.Image orgImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
            System.Drawing.Rectangle CropArea = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
                Convert.ToInt32(X.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(Y.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(W.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(H.Value));
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(CropArea.Width, CropArea.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(orgImg, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height), CropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    cropFileName = SID + Session["fileEx"];
                    cropFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/StaffPhoto"), cropFileName);
                    bitMap.Save(cropFilePath);
                    bitMap.Dispose();
                    string At = ddlAT.SelectedValue;
                    if (Session["UpdateP"].ToString() == "a")
                    {
                        string upMessage = "You are trying to update the information for staff: " + SID;
                        string no = "1";
                        Response.Redirect("AlertUpdate.aspx?MessageNO=" + no + "&UpdateMessage=" + upMessage + "&UpdateStaffid=" + SID + "&fileN=" + cropFileName + "&NewPass=" + newP + "&UserT=" + ut + "&DelFile=" + fileName, false);
                    }
                    else if (Session["UpdateP"].ToString() == "b")
                    {
                        string upMessage = "You are trying to update the information for staff: " + SID;
                        string no = "2";
                        Response.Redirect("AlertUpdate.aspx?MessageNO=" + no + "&UpdateMessage=" + upMessage + "&UpdateStaffid=" + SID + "&fileN=" + cropFileName + "&NewPass=" + newP + "&UserT=" + ut + "&DelFile=" + fileName, false);
                    }
                    g.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lbMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally {
                orgImg.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AlertUpdate Code Behind sample

```
string strsql = "select UserType FROM Account WHERE UserID='" + OID + "'";
                DataTable dt = sql.ExecTable(strsql);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    uStaffA.UpdateAccountbaseOnStaffID(OID, OID, ut);
                }
```

Updateaccountbaseonstaffid

```
public int UpdateAccountbaseOnStaffID(string staffid, string NStaffId, string ut)
    {
        StringBuilder sql;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        int result = 0;
        //int newOrderId = 0;
        // create order header
        SqlConnection conn = dbConn.GetConnection();
        sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendLine("UPDATE Account");
        sql.AppendLine("SET UserID=@Nid, StaffID=@Nid, UserType=@UserType where StaffID=@Oid");

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Oid", staffid);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nid", NStaffId);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", ut);

            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return result;

    }
```

AlertUpdateSuc

```
public partial class AlertUpdateSuc : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["MesNo"].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
        }
        else if (Request.QueryString["MesNo"].ToString() == "2")
        {
            Response.Redirect("StaffListAdSearch.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

In short even though the photo updates correctly, the old photo is still being displayed until i refresh the page.

Any ideas will be helpful! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, In order to rebind your photo correctly, what you have to do is to update the Image URL.

However, because our Image URL never changes, what i had to do was add in some data into the URL so that it becomes unique and updates correctly.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Image img = e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
            string url = img.ImageUrl;
            string modified = url + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            img.ImageUrl = modified;
        }
    }
```

By doing what i did above, the Image in the GridView will be updated.
This works for DetailsView as well, by simply doing it this way:

```
protected void ViewEmployeeDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = ViewEmployeeDetails.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
        string url = img.ImageUrl;
        string modified = url + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        img.ImageUrl = modified;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update the image, it does not mean that your gridview also have to be updated. Nothing will be executed itself. You have to make command to be executed. After updating your image you have to call rebinding of your gridview.

Comment: also next time post your code behind also, it also make a sense

Comment: Not necessarily. He is using declarative datasource and in such case you don't need to rebind manually. It gets rebinded automatically.

Comment: @Rahul take a look on *datasource* again please. He don't have an *UpdateCommand*

Comment: My update isn't from an updatecommand, i have a select button that brings up a page that allows me to change the data there

Comment: @SebastianHeng the problem is that you have to rebind your gridview, as you don't work with it while updating. DataSource binds your gridview on the page_load, and it will not be rebinded automatically: postback should occur or you have to rebind. You use an updatepanel, so you don't need postback. You just need to rebind your gridview

Comment: To rebind, i have to do a GridView1.DataBind() right? I have already done that on Page_Load() but it still does not update.

Comment: Call it in the end of your Update method

Comment: I don't see your code behind, so I can't say exactly where to add, caz' you may have a different logic

Comment: From what I did, the select button is what will bring me to where i can update the items. Because of that, i'm not sure how to call it at the end when the Update method is from another page, hence i called it on Page load.

Comment: @SebastianHeng I need your update_click method, not selectedindexchanged

Comment: @Khazratbek yeah I just added it in, sorry was copying and pasting the codes

Comment: @SebastianHeng I guess you are misunderstanding me. I need your method, that called *update_click*. In your current page, not from another

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the update_click method.


        protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
            string rowNumber = grdrow.Cells[1].Text;
            Response.Redirect("StaffUpdate.aspx?Staffid=" + rowNumber);
            

        }

Comment: and your StaffUpdate page's code behind consist of btnCrop_Click method only?

Comment: No, but that's where i save the Image to the StaffID. I've posted the full lines of codes already

Comment: @SebastianHeng I don't see the code, where you redirecting to the old page after cropping your images and updating that. You are going back, using *BACK* button of your browser? lol

Comment: No, i'm using Response.Redirect("StaffListAdSearch.aspx");. Sorry for confusion. It redirects to a page that simply has a popup to tell them that it' has been added correctly. Then it'll redirect to the StaffListAdSearch, where the gridview is

Comment: by your codes I suspect that all uploading has been made in AlertUpdate?

Comment: not all, the photo is uploaded in StaffUpdate. This line makes the upload - myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("~\\StaffPhoto\\Ori\\" + fileName), myimg.RawFormat);

however, the other fields are uploaded from AlertUpdate

Comment: @SebastianHeng it is so complicated... Add your ALertUpdate also

Comment: @SebastianHeng I still can't see your *update tablename set field = value* codes...

Comment: added the codebehind for that. I had to cut the AlertUpdate code behind as it was too long, but here's what is used to update the other values, apart from the photo

Comment: you have that, but I don't see the relation between your selectsql query and your code behind. Can you give teamviewer to look on it as a whole item? If no, I even don't know how to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, as my school does not allow us to use TeamViewer. Thank you anyways though! I'll try and figure it out more.